# calculate growth

Tags: sql, sql-server

Calculate grow rate disk

What is the best way, with the data below, to produce a query for forecasting disk space requirements for the next 6 months, 
and what was the growth rate for the last 3 months

The fields are:

- Server - server
- DiskName - diskname
- PctFree - Percentage of free disk space
- PctUsed - Percentage of disk space used
- FreeMB -  Freespace in MB
- FreeGB - Freespace in MB
- TotalSizeMB - Total disk Space in MB
- TotalSizeGB - Total disk Space in GB
- sysdate - Collection Date

```
CREATE TABLE #data( [Server] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,[DiskName] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [PctFree] [int] NOT NULL,[PctUsed] [int] NOT NULL,[FreeMB] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [FreeGB] [decimal](10, 1) NOT NULL, [TotalSizeMB] [bigint] NOT NULL,[TotalSizeGB] [decimal](10, 1) NOT NULL,
    [sysdate] [datetime] NOT NULL) 


INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk01', 11, 89, 138216, N'134.0', 1228798, N'1199.0', N'2019-06-11 10:22:21.753')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk01', 26, 74, 388534, N'379.0', 1484798, N'1449.0', N'2019-06-17 10:21:51.997')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk01', 24, 76, 357814, N'349.0', 1484798, N'1449.0', N'2019-07-15 10:22:28.487')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk01', 23, 77, 350646, N'342.0', 1484798, N'1449.0', N'2019-07-22 10:23:22.600')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk01', 22, 78, 334774, N'326.0', 1484798, N'1449.0', N'2019-08-05 10:25:42.357')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk01', 22, 78, 327094, N'319.0', 1484798, N'1449.0', N'2019-08-12 10:23:54.910')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk01', 21, 79, 316342, N'308.0', 1484798, N'1449.0', N'2019-08-26 10:23:38.117')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk01', 21, 79, 316342, N'308.0', 1484798, N'1449.0', N'2019-09-02 10:24:28.940')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk02', 13, 87, 106219, N'103.0', 767869, N'749.0', N'2019-06-11 10:22:21.753')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk02', 58, 42, 960233, N'937.0', 1638269, N'1599.0', N'2019-06-17 10:21:51.997')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk02', 54, 46, 887529, N'866.0', 1638269, N'1599.0', N'2019-07-15 10:22:28.487')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk02', 53, 47, 871145, N'850.0', 1638269, N'1599.0', N'2019-07-22 10:23:22.600')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk02', 50, 50, 832745, N'813.0', 1638269, N'1599.0', N'2019-08-05 10:25:42.357')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk02', 49, 51, 814313, N'795.0', 1638269, N'1599.0', N'2019-08-12 10:23:54.910')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk02', 47, 53, 783593, N'765.0', 1638269, N'1599.0', N'2019-08-26 10:23:38.117')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'server1', N'Disk02', 47, 53, 783593, N'765.0', 1638269, N'1599.0', N'2019-09-02 10:24:28.940')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 3, 97, 171101, N'167.0', 5210801, N'5088.0', N'2018-05-09 12:12:37.167')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 13, 87, 690293, N'674.0', 5210801, N'5088.0', N'2018-06-11 11:09:37.927')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 10, 90, 566847, N'553.0', 5210801, N'5088.0', N'2018-07-02 10:25:47.597')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 9, 91, 532709, N'520.0', 5415601, N'5288.0', N'2018-07-16 11:04:49.643')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 7, 93, 409905, N'400.0', 5415601, N'5288.0', N'2018-08-14 00:34:05.333')
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 11, 89, 610264, N'595.0', 5415601, N'5288.0', N'2018-09-17 10:18:03.857' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 21, 79, 1146957, N'1120.0', 5415601, N'5288.0', N'2018-10-01 10:18:05.423' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 9, 91, 497969, N'486.0', 5415601, N'5288.0', N'2018-10-29 10:18:04.183' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 4, 96, 240764, N'235.0', 5415601, N'5288.0', N'2018-11-12 10:18:02.750' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 6, 94, 368653, N'360.0', 5620401, N'5488.0', N'2018-12-03 10:18:04.833' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 9, 91, 562652, N'549.0', 6144689, N'6000.0', N'2018-12-31 10:18:05.113' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 7, 93, 470230, N'459.0', 6144689, N'6000.0', N'2019-01-07 10:18:05.000' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 20, 80, 1598828, N'1561.0', 7717389, N'7536.0', N'2019-01-28 10:18:04.273' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 20, 80, 1598828, N'1561.0', 7717389, N'7536.0', N'2019-02-04 10:18:04.577' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 20, 80, 1598828, N'1561.0', 7717389, N'7536.0', N'2019-03-04 10:18:04.337' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 10, 90, 780182, N'761.0', 7717389, N'7536.0', N'2019-04-08 10:18:04.863' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 2, 98, 215328, N'210.0', 7717389, N'7536.0', N'2019-05-06 10:18:05.300' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 1, 99, 131081, N'128.0', 8024589, N'7836.0', N'2019-06-03 10:18:05.177' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 1, 99, 131081, N'128.0', 8024589, N'7836.0', N'2019-07-08 10:18:09.650' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 1, 99, 131081, N'128.0', 8024589, N'7836.0', N'2019-08-12 10:18:10.113' )
INSERT [dbo].[#data] ([Server], [DiskName], [PctFree], [PctUsed], [FreeMB], [FreeGB], [TotalSizeMB], [TotalSizeGB], [sysdate] ) VALUES (N'Server2', N'Disk03', 1, 99, 173021, N'168.0', 8894989, N'8686.0', N'2019-09-02 10:18:09.597' )

select * from #data;

drop table #data
```

Comment: Please show the results that you want and a bit more explanation on how *you* define growth rate.

Comment: The intention is to calculate the need for the disks that are below 10 %, an calculate the space requirement for the next 6 months taking into account the decrease in free space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT d1.[Server], d1.[DiskName]
    , d1.[Last Measure]
    , [State] = CASE WHEN d2.[FreeMB]*1./d2.[TotalSizeMB] < .1 THEN 'Below ' ELSE 'Abowe ' END + ' 10%'
    , [Last Free, GB] = d2.[FreeGB]
    , [Free, %] = CAST(d2.[FreeMB]*100./d2.[TotalSizeMB] as DECIMAL(7,3))
    , [1 Month Growth, GB] = CAST(((d2.[TotalSizeMB] - d2.[FreeMB]) - (d3.[TotalSizeMB] - d3.[FreeMB])) * [1Month] / 1024 as DECIMAL(19,3))
    , [6 Month Growth, GB] = CAST(((d2.[TotalSizeMB] - d2.[FreeMB]) - (d3.[TotalSizeMB] - d3.[FreeMB])) * [6Month] / 1024 as DECIMAL(19,3))
    , [Will need in 6 Month, GB] = 
        CASE WHEN ((d2.[TotalSizeMB] - d2.[FreeMB]) - (d3.[TotalSizeMB] - d3.[FreeMB])) * [6Month] > d2.[FreeMB]
            THEN CAST((((d2.[TotalSizeMB] - d2.[FreeMB]) - (d3.[TotalSizeMB] - d3.[FreeMB])) * [6Month] - d2.[FreeMB]) / 1024 as DECIMAL(19,3))
            ELSE 0 END
    , [6 Month Date] = DATEADD(MONTH,6,d1.[Last Measure])
FROM (
    SELECT [Server], [DiskName]
        , [Last Measure] = MAX(sysdate)
        , [First Measure] = MIN(sysdate)
        , [6Month] = 262080./DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(sysdate),MAX(sysdate))
        , [1Month] = 43680./DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(sysdate),MAX(sysdate))
    FROM #data GROUP BY [Server], [DiskName]) as d1
INNER JOIN #data as d2
    ON d1.[Server] = d2.[Server] 
        AND d1.[DiskName] = d2.[DiskName]
        AND d2.sysdate = d1.[Last Measure]
INNER JOIN #data as d3
    ON d1.[Server] = d3.[Server] 
        AND d1.[DiskName] = d3.[DiskName]
        AND d3.sysdate = d1.[First Measure];
```